# I became a trusted user, I got a non-working button as a prize? :)

Tags: support, bug, reputation, tag-wiki

After answering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39651677/c-how-can-i-edit-a-c-string-in-a-function-without-using-malloc) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603659/spark-application-uses-only-1-executor), I reached 20k rep and I become a trusted user! O Lala Lala!!! Who could thought it? I mean 3+ years ago, I wanted to reach 1k rep, which seemed like the upper bound for myself at that time, but [my top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716255/why-does-this-program-print-forked-4-times/26716300#26716300) really got me a big boost, and here I am!

Anyway, to the point George! After reading the Trusted User related text in the Help Center, it mentioned something about tag wikis, which I think is relevant to the behavior I am encountering right now.

I am trying to edit [textselection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/textselection), but no matter of the numerous times I pressed the button, it will refresh instantly and nothing will happen, just like a Magikarp's splash!

I [tried debugging it really hard](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/18/bd/95/18bd95236b44de41b113ad142ab6fd1f.jpg), but nothing.

Notice that I already edited some wiki tags yesterday, and I think I hit the limit. I just want SO to know about it, that's all! :) I am tagging this as a bug, but come on, that's a puppy!

Comment: 3+ years ago i wanted to reach 1k rep too......only just got it today, rub it in why don't you. also i assume that Yahoo thing at the bottom is a reference to them getting hacked?

Comment: It seems that I have contributed in your 1k rep @Memor-X, I wonder if you have too to my 20k! :) What is hack? Baby don't crack me... :)))

Comment: Ah a new delete vote enabled user to fix on :) congrats!

Comment: Puppies are much appreciated, they have powers beyond what you can imagine actually :)

Comment: Soooo... you're basically bragging that you did so much work you broke the button? If so: that's awesome and keep wrecking this site.

Comment: @gsamaras Can you try it again now.  I am able to access the edit page for the tag.  Otherwise what happens when you go to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/19691)?

Comment: @NathanOliver now it allows me to, let me post an answer!

Comment: We don't *actually* trust you.  The site is obligated to show you the button, but we had a discussion about it and decided to disable it behind the scenes for you.  Nobody wanted to confront you about it.  Sorry, we're wusses.

Comment: I don't know what a wusse is @Will, but it seems you are telling the truth... :)

Comment: Oh @Will now I understood what you meant. A non-trusted user gsamaras it is!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems that the system got confused from my 20k rep and the new privileges I was given w.r.t. to the wiki tags and the fact that I had probably reached the daily limit on editing the tag wiki.

Moreover it would say Create Tag Wiki on some and Edit on others, but I really didn't check why.

PS - today I am able to edit the tag wiki.

Comment: That is one heckova run-on sentence.  Had to read it 3 times to understand.